# Test::More: Bad plan due to a escape sequence

Tags: perl, winapi, testing, escaping, perl-module

When I run the following test for this module the test fails.

When I add a newline to the escape sequence ["\e(U"](https://metacpan.org/module/Win32%3a%3aConsole%3a%3aANSI#Escape-sequences-for-Select-Character-Set) the test passes.

Why would this escape sequence cause to fail the test this way?

---

```
package My_Module;

use Win32::Console::ANSI;

print "\e(U"; # dissables the so-called ANSI to OEM conversion

# print "\e(U\n" # written this way, the test passes.

1;
```

---

```
use Test::More tests => 1; 

BEGIN { use_ok( 'My_Module' ) || print "Bail out!\n" }

diag( "Testing My_Module, Perl $], $^X" );
```

Result:

```
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/00-load.t .. # Testing My_Module, Perl 5.018001, C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe
t/00-load.t .. Failed 1/1 subtests

Test Summary Report
-------------------
t/00-load.t (Wstat: 0 Tests: 0 Failed: 0)
  Parse errors: Bad plan.  You planned 1 tests but ran 0.
Files=1, Tests=0,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.03 usr +  0.05 sys =  0.08 CPU)
Result: FAIL
Failed 1/1 test programs. 0/0 subtests failed.
dmake:  Error code 255, while making 'test_dynamic'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run your test in verbose mode, you will see that the output of your test is:

```
←(Uok 1 - use MyModule;
```

that's not reconigzed by perl as a success test, it should be:
`ok 1 - use MyModule;` see the [TAP specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol).

If you add a \n to the module print secuence `print "\e(U\n"`, it probably pass the test, but I don't know if this is wrong for your purposes.

I think the best way to test an output is the use of [Test::Output](http://search.cpan.org/~bdfoy/Test-Output-1.02/lib/Test/Output.pm).

Comment: As another workaround I've tried `INIT{ print"\e(U" }`. This way the test is OK too. Maybe this is better than adding a newline.